# Getting Started with JAVA and Selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to JAVA and Selenium, I installed both Eclipse and Selenium webdriver and I'm trying my first example (search a keyword in Google):

```
package testproject;

public class testclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Object driver;
        //Open Home Page
        ((Object) driver).get("http://www.google.com");
        //Enter text in search box
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("selenium");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        //Click Search button
        ((By) driver).findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();
        Thread.sleep(10000);  
    }
}
```

**I got the following exception:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problems:  The method get(String) is undefined for the type Object By
>   cannot be resolved By cannot be resolved to a type By cannot be
>   resolved at testproject.testclass.main(testclass.java:10) Picked up
>   JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook**

Comment: The `Object` class doesn't have a get method. Whatever the `driver` object is, it should be a type that has a `get` method.

Comment: @sourh I would actually try to find a working example, and just try to run that, unchanged. What you have here is wrong in many, many ways. (And if this is an actual example you've found, post the URL here, so that others can know *never* to go there)

Comment: @Andy yes, I will be very thankful please, my goal now is to run a working example.

Answer (score 0):

you should import the selenium some class ,you can use the some methods and you ought crate a drive instance

Answer (score 0):

Use org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver instead of Object. If you cannot import it, download the Selenium Standalone Server from http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/ and add it to your external libraries.

In Eclipse you can add it with click right to your project > properties > Java Build Path > Add External Jars.

You also have to create the WebDriver Object easiest with

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```